# I am making a visual C# winform application. I want to store data in it

Tags: c#, database, winforms, file-io

rom what i know i can either save it in a database or  through file io. The data has to be locally stored and i don't want data in datagrid view . 
If i store the data through file handling then how can in store data in the directory where the software will be installed. I have tried service based database(.mdf format) and can't get it work. I need it for project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create files, you will be using the [System.IO.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. This gives you access to methods such as Create(), CreateText(), WriteAllBytes(). Which method you use will depend on what type of data you are using.

To save the file in your application directory, you can get the path using [AppDomain.BaseDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

So for example if you're storing plain text, you could do something similar to

```
public static void WriteSomeText(string text) 
{
    string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.BaseDirectory, "mytextfile.txt");
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
    {
        sw.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you timothy found what i wanted.